# Sudo via net::ssh in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, sudo

Here's how at the moment I send commands to a remote server:

```
Net::SSH.start("1.2.3.4", keys: ["~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"]) do |ssh|
  ssh.exec!(cmd_item)
end
```

How would I execute a command which requires root, that is "sudo apt-get install for example" which having me to type in the password each time?

Comment: How about doing `sudo su -` first?

Comment: @Jordan, those are different servers. How would that help me? `sudo su - ` on on 1st server will have no effect on a remote one.

Comment: I did not say to do it on the local machine. Your question led me to believe you meant "each time" within the same SSH session. If that's not the case you should clarify your question.

Comment: @Jordan no, I shouldn't.

Comment: Lol. Okay. Good luck solving your problem. 

Comment: @Jordan. Dol. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Net SSH to execute commands with sudo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356878/using-net-ssh-to-execute-commands-with-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the root password for the remote machine. If that is known, the rest should be possible this way:

```
Net::SSH.start("1.2.3.4", keys: ["~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"]) do |ssh|
   if not cmd_item["sudo "].nil? # if cmd_item string requires sudo access
       # sudo yourcommand  =>  echo -e "RemoteRootPassword\n" | sudo -S yourcommand
       cmd_item = "echo -e \"RemoteRootPassword\n\" | " + cmd_item.gsub(/sudo/, "sudo -S")
       ssh.exec!(cmd_item)
   else
       ssh.exec!(cmd_item)
   end
end
```

For some reference, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter) question on how to use sudo with password as parameter.

Hope it helps : )

Answer (score 0):

If you have root privileges on the remote server, I would set up sudoers to allow the user you use for ssh run passwordless sudo. You can be really specific about the commands you want to allow without password. In terms of security your ssh key should provide a better level of authentication than a password anyway.

If you not control the server and it would be a hassle to ask the admin to allow you to sudo without password, the [Net::SSH documentation](http://net-ssh.rubyforge.org/ssh/v2/api/index.html) gives a neat example of how you can respond to the password prompt:

```
Net::SSH.start("host", "user") do |ssh|
  ssh.exec! "cp /some/file /another/location"
  hostname = ssh.exec!("hostname")

  ssh.open_channel do |ch|
    ch.exec "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ls" do |ch, success|
      abort "could not execute sudo ls" unless success

      ch.on_data do |ch, data|
        print data
        if data =~ /sudo password: /
          ch.send_data("password\n")
        end
      end
    end
  end

  ssh.loop
end
```